# C++11 lambda capture by copy unless wrapped in std::ref

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stl

When passing the arguments to `std::bind` they are always copied or moved, unless wrapped by std::ref and I want to do the same with a lambda expression.
The Problem is, that I want to wrap the generation of the lambda expression in a function and forward the arguments as passed by the user to the lambda. The reason I want to do this, is that I want to call the lambda asynchronously and let the user decide if the arguments shall be passed by reference or by copy.

Consider the following example. I have the function `print_address` that takes the parameter as reference. Then I have the function `combine_and_call_bind` that forwards the arguments into `std::bind`.

```
void print_address(int& a) {
  std::cout << "Adress of a = " << &a << std::endl;
}

template<typename F, typename Args>
void combine_and_call_bind(F f, Args&& args) {
  auto a = std::bind(f, std::forward<Args>(args));

  a();
}
```

The user can the specify when calling the `combine_and_call_bind`-function if the arguments shall be copied into `std::bind` or if they shall be passed by reference by wrapping the arguments in `std::ref`:

```
combine_and_call_bind(print_address, a); // copy a into std::bind
combine_and_call_bind(print_address, std::ref(a)); // pass a as reference into std::bind
```

How can I do the same with the following function `combine_and_call_lambda`, while using C++11?

```
template<typename F, typename Args>
void combine_and_call_lambda(F f, Args&& args) {
  auto a = [/* std::forward<Args>(args) */, f] {
    f(args);
  };

  a();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `address` is the correct spelling.

Comment: `&`? (11 more to go)

Comment: @user202729 edited ;) If I capture the variable as `&` it's only going to be passed as reference, or can I specify to capture it by copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to capture everything by value:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void combine_and_call_lambda(F f, Args&&... args) {
    auto a = [=]() mutable {
        f(args...);
    };

    a();
}
```

Then use:

```
combine_and_call_lambda(print_address, a);
combine_and_call_lambda(print_address, std::ref(a));
```

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/g/RbD12d)

As we can see at [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> captures - a comma-separated list of zero or more captures, optionally
>   beginning with a capture-default.
>
> Capture list can be passed as follows (see below for the detailed
>   description):
>
> ...
>
> [=] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda
>   **by copy** and current object by reference if exists

So, in the code above everything is copied and stored inside the lambda object.